# how to open file explorer and browse a file without tkinter

Tags: python, windows

I wanted to create an app that takes an image file then does some work on it and returns another file.

so, my question is how can I open file explorer so the user can select the file that he wants to make a change on?

by opening file explorer I mean like the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlNuh.png)

so that the user can select that image file and then make whatever changes.

I don't want to use any GUIs because the app will run in the python console.

Any Idea??

Comment: I think `easygui` and `plyer` modules offer file browsers. Also, if you do `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` you wouldn't need to build your own GUI.

Comment: Your title says Explorer but your screenshot shows the Open common dialog which is not part of "Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use tkinter (cause tkinter is mainly for guis which you don't want) but try it out and see if it helps

```
import os
import subprocess
FILEBROWSER_PATH = os.path.join(os.getenv('WINDIR'), 'explorer.exe')

def explore(path):
    # explorer would choke on forward slashes
    path = os.path.normpath(path)

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        subprocess.run([FILEBROWSER_PATH, path])
    elif os.path.isfile(path):
        subprocess.run([FILEBROWSER_PATH, '/select,', os.path.normpath(path)])
```

Comment: This opens a Explorer window, the OP really wants the Open file common dialog that allows you to get back a file path from the users selection...